# how to format an API call with access token in JavaScript

Tags: json, p5.js

I can't figure out how to make a request with an access token from JS. I have the API documentation here: https://littlesis.org/api

I'm using P5.js as well

```
this.url = 'https://littlesis.org/api/entities/search?q=' + this.name;
        httpDo(
            this.url, {
                method: 'GET',
                // Other Request options, like special headers for apis
                headers: {
                    'Littlesis-Api-Token': 'xxxxx'
                }
            },
            function(res) {
                println("!");
            }
        );
```

This doesn't seem to work, and it gives me the following error: "NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource."

Is there a way to simply place the access token in the URL? That way I can retrieve the JSON the old fashion way.

Comment: Does using their example Curl work? `curl -H 'Littlesis-Api-Token: RhS3mQneriAaym4pNjdjw' https://littlesis.org/api/entities/search?q=Example`

Comment: Could also potentially be a CORS issue, that error is often symptomatic of an access control issue.

Comment: How would I resolve a CORS issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a no-cors option to your request:

```
this.url = 'https://littlesis.org/api/entities/search?q=' + this.name;
    httpDo(
        this.url, {
            method: 'GET',
            mode: 'no-cors',
            // Other Request options, like special headers for apis
            headers: {
                'Littlesis-Api-Token': 'xxxxx'
            }
        },
        function(res) {
            println("!");
        }
    );
```

At least for me, this changes the error from a 422 unproccessable entity error to a 401 unauthorized error, which I assume your actual API key will resolve.

Comment: Progress! I now get a Error: "null"
    promise http://localhost:8000/p5.js:69769. I guess "res" is coming back null?

Comment: If you open the network tab in your browser's inspector, what do you see when that request is made? Status code, errors, anything like that?

Comment: My guess is that `res.body` is coming back null due to some other error.

Comment: Ah yes I am getting 401 unauthorized. I wonder if it is meant to be formatted differently, as in the Littlesis-Api-Token part?

Comment: From the docs page you linked: `The API will return status code 401 if you forget to include the Littlesis-Api-Token header and will return state code 403 if the token is invalid` so it seems like it's somehow not seeing the authorization header. Unclear why though.

Comment: I'm wondering if maybe it should look different, like this? headers: {
     authorization: 'Littlesis-Api-Token: Y0zU725McX2pfN4cRPiSvA'
    }

Comment: Okay, I see what's happening. You're between a rock and a hard place here. Disabling CORS protection removes your ability to add certain headers, resulting in a 401, while enabling CORS protection stops the request from going through at all because it's a violation of CORS rules, resulting in a 422. The *actual* solution here would be to properly set up the Access-control-origin header on their end -- either they are intentionally blocking CORS access from other domains, in which case what we are trying to do is not allowed, or they've unintentionally misconfigured it.

Comment: Either way, we can't fix that problem without contacting the API maintainers. If it's just the data you need, though, consider making a call for this resource from a non-web-browser source, so CORS protections are not tripped. Lastly, you may want to delete your API key from public Stackoverflow.